# jquery array with attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I want to create an array like this in JQuery:

```
id=1, name="pepe"
```

How can I do this? I have done this but not working

```
arr[idx]["id"].push( $(id).text());
arr[idx]["name"].push( $(name).text());
```

to later access to the id of the array like this:

```
(arr[0].id)
```

Comment: the array will still be just Javascript, no jQuery has to be involved. Do you want to populate the array with jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to have an array where each *entry* in the array has `id` and `name` attributes, here's how:

Declare a variable:

```
var arr;
```

Create the array:

```
arr = [];
```

Add an entry to it which is an object with those properties:

```
arr.push({
    id:   $(id).text(),  // I assume the `id` in `$(id)` is just placeholder for something
    name: $(name).text() // Similarly the `name` in `$(name)`
});
```

In the above, provided `$(id).text()` returns `"1"` and `$(name).text()` returns `"Pepe"`, you'll end up with an array with one entry, where that one entry is an object with `id=1` and `name=Pepe`.

Then you can access (say) the first of those:

```
console.log(arr[0].id);  // Shows the `id` property of the first object in the array
```

Comment: Thanks, and later how can I access to the id value for example? arr[0].id?

Comment: @user3383415: Yes, that's right (that's at the very bottom of the answer; I don't recall, maybe I added it with an edit just after posting).

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.push({id:1, name:"pepe"});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr[idx].id = $(id).text();
arr[idx].name = $(name).text();
```